# Angular JS custom table directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In the project I am working on I have a lot of serial true/false data that needs to be displayed in different ways. I have been working on a directive that will allow me to pass in the model, the table header, and heres the tricky part, number of columns.

```
<serial-checkbox-table title="Title" columns="2" ng-model="items"></serial-checkbox-table>
```

I cant seem to get the columns parameter to be respected. I built this thing at one point where the html was generated in the link phase but I was having a hard time updating the model that was passed into the directive.

heres a jsfiddle of the current state of the directive.

http://jsfiddle.net/peledies/2tVAe/

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what is the problem can you make it more clear?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the `columns` variable to do? I updated your jsfiddle to properly output the ending </td></tr> but I'm not sure if this what you want.  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/callado4/2tVAe/3/

Comment: i would expect the columns parameter to let me specify how many colums the table has. if i say columns='2' i should have 2 cells then a new row. If i say columns='3' i should have 3 cells and then a new row.

Comment: You aren't even using the columns parameter to create the cells. I see that the colspan in the header row is being set correctly. When you have more than 2 columns, do you just  want the other cells to be empty?

Comment: I think this is a more accurate example of how I intend to use this directive http://jsfiddle.net/peledies/2tVAe/6/ it works but when I click the 'update model' button i want the table to be recompiled. and it doesnt do that. thats why i went with the ngrepeat template, because it would redraw the table when the data changed.

Comment: In that case then you need a $scope.$watch. I'm updating the jsfiddle now to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a $scope.$watch on the `model` variable.

Here is your old cold:

```
var model = $scope.$eval($attrs.ngModel);
...
// compile and write to dom
```

Needs to updated to

```
$scope.$watch($attrs.ngModel,function(newVal,oldVal) {
    //var model = $scope.$eval($attrs.ngModel);
    // can just take model value from watch function result
    var model = newVal;
    ...
    // compile and write to dom
});
```

And here is your jsfiddle updated with this logic: http://jsfiddle.net/callado4/2tVAe/7/